# VB net and postgres : Getting "An operation is already in progress" using npgsql

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, visual-studio-2013, npgsql

I'm using the following code to retrieve a list of objects (products) and another list (sizes) inside of them.

```
Dim l As New List(Of Entidades.producto)

Dim c As New NpgsqlCommand("select id, name from product", cn)
Dim r As NpgsqlDataReader = c.ExecuteReader

Do While r.Read

    Dim p As New Entidades.product
    p.ID = r.Item("id")
    p.name = r.Item("name")
    l.Add(p)

    >>> I HAD THE OTHER LOOP HERE BUT HAVING THE SAME ISSUE TRIED TO PUT THE
    READER OUTSIDE OF THIS LOOP.

Loop

r.Close()

For Each p In l
    c = New NpgsqlCommand("select t.id id, t.name nombre from productsize pt join size t on t.id = pt.sizeid where productid = :productid order by ord", cn)
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("productid", pgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, p.ID)
    c.Prepare() <---- HERE I GET THE ERROR

    Dim rt As NpgsqlDataReader = c.ExecuteReader

    Do While rt.Read

        Dim t As New size
        t.ID = rt.Item("id")
        t.nombre = rt.Item("name")
        p.size.Add(t)

    Loop

Next


Return l
```

And I'm getting the "An operation is already in progress" error when I execute the prepare.

I thought closing the reader was enough so I could run another.

Comment: I don't know Postgres but I would check if the provider supports the MultipleActiveResultSets=True configuration setting in the connection string. In that case you don't need anymore two loops and can reuse a connection while it is serving a first reader

Answer (score 1):

The second loop was not closing the reader, and when I called the function again, it exploded.